# How to make post action accept array parameters?

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form in which there is a bunch of dynamically generated checkboxes. Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Foo[]" value="1"/> Bar
<input type="checkbox" name="Foo[]" value="2"/> Baz
<input type="checkbox" name="Foo[]" value="2"/> Bay
```

I had a `int[] Foo` property in my model and I expected it to be filled with the data from those checkboxes, but it's value is always null (regardless of whether I check any of the checkboxes or not). Since this failed I just added `int[] Foo` as a plain old parameter to the action just to make is it wasn't something caused by the model, but `Foo` was still null.

I checked what browser has to say about my post, but the values from the checkboxes are there (if I check them of course).

> Foo[] = 1
>   Foo[] = 2
>   Foo[] = 3

As a last resort I added `FormCollection form` to the action parameters and I can see `Foo[]` actually appearing in the form data.

So waht am I doing wrong here? How to make an action accept an array query parameter?

Comment: using your `int[] Foo` model as the argument to your action have you tried using `name="Foo[0]"` `name="Foo[1]"` etc?

Comment: @wal Rather than adding id to the name of the inputs, I removed the `[]` part and it solved my problem. Turns out array parameters in MVC are handled differently from those in PHP and I just tried to do it the PHP way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got enlightened (while taking a break to make some tea). The fact that in the `FormCollection form` the parameter was called `Foo[]` rather than just `Foo` lead my to the source of the problem. The only time I did this kind of form in the past was when I was working on PHP projects. Naming the checkbox inputs `Foo[]` was the right way to do this in PHP (I think). Turns out, if I want to do the same in MVC I have to omit the `[]` and it'll work.

In short for my MVC app my inputs should have looked like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Foo" value="1"/> Bar
<input type="checkbox" name="Foo" value="2"/> Baz
<input type="checkbox" name="Foo" value="2"/> Bay
```